# fluent nhibernate table per concrete class mapping of IList of abstract baseClass

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have an abstract BaseClass, and 2 DerivedClasses.
I also have an OwnerClass, which holds an `IList` of type BaseClass.

I mapped the classes according to the Table Per Concrete Class (TPC) model:
(forgive me if I have syntax mistakes in my code, I re-written my code on notepad since my real code is not reachable for now)

```
public class BaseClassMap : ClassMap<BaseClass>
{
    public BaseClassMap()
    {
        // ID + Fields Mapping... 

        UseUnionSubClassForInheritanceMapping(); 
    }
}

public class DerivedClass1Map : SubclassMap<DerivedClass1>
{
    public DerivedClass1Map()
    {
        // Fields Mapping...
    }
}

public class DerivedClass2Map : SubclassMap<DerivedClass2>
{
    public DerivedClass1Map()
    {
        // Fields Mapping...
    }
}

public class OwnerClassMap : ClassMap<OwnerClas>
{
    public OwnerClassMap()
    {
        // ID + Fields Mapping...

        HasMany(x => x.BaseClassList).Cascade().All();

        // Option 2 - Using Inverse:
        // HasMany(x => x.BaseClassList).Cascade().All().Inverse();
    }
}
```

I configured the nhibernate to create the tables for me by the mapping. For each DerivedClass a table was create with a new column named 'Owner_Id'. For the abstract BaseClass no table was created, as I expected.

I created some BaseClasses objects and filled them with (new) DerivedClass1 and DerivedClass2.
I created an Owner object and added to its list the BaseClasses objects.

When I tried to save the Owner object I get

> GenericADOException: could not insert collection... SQL: UPDATE
>   BaseClass...

I was surprised to see that it tries to access a table named 'BaseClass' since there wasn't such table!

I tried option 2 in OwnerClass mapping - to add Inverse(). When I saved the Owner object the result was that the owner object was saved in the Owner table, and the DerivedClasses objects were saved in their tables but with no value at their 'Owner_Id' column.

Why do I need to use Inverse()? and more important, why there is no value in the 'Owner_Id' column?

Comment: inverse on the collection tells NHibernate that the backreference on the other side should maintain the association, but since you have none inverse should be false. it looks like a bug

Comment: did you find a solution for this? i encounter a very similar problem... thanks :)